# count frequency values of all csv

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I have a large csv file (without header or index), for example

```
A T C G
G T A C
CT T A G
G G G G
```

I want to count all values in all csv (not for special column or row), the output will be:

```
A 3
T 3
C 2
G 7
CT 1
```

How can I do this with Linux?

Comment: homework question? what have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: Given the lack of constraints on the solution, perhaps this question would be better suited to [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) where people can answer the question in 18+ obscure programming languages?

Comment: @24601 no it's not homework but this steps I really need it in my project .. I search and try some code but it's give me the result that I want .. Often they need to count for specific column not like me

Comment: @matigo yesterday I try to do this with python but it's take long time and in the end the kernal was died .. And I have only python and linux thus I want it in linux if it possible because I can't download other programming languages :(

Comment: You could match any whole word using the PCRE pattern `\w+`: `grep -oP "\w+" my.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn`. Check also ripgrep

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to accomplish this with any number of programming languages but, if you're looking for something that will work on just about any Linux-based machine without requiring additional libraries, you can do something like this:

```
cat {filename} | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'
```

<sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace *only* `{filename}` with the name of the file containing the data you wish to parse.</sup>

Using your sample data set *copied into a file several times* gives the following result:

```
G 77
T 33
A 33
C 22
CT 11
```

#### How this works

This is actually the combination of multiple common Linux commands. This is how they work

| Command | What it does |
| --- | --- |
| `cat {filename}` | Read a given file |
| `tr -s ' ' '\n'` | Translate (or Transliterate, depending on who you ask) the spaces to newlines, which puts all strings on a distinct line. |
| `sort` | Sort the strings |
| `uniq -c` | Count unique strings |
| `sort -r` | Reverse the sort result |
| `awk '{ print $2, $1 }'` | Scan the sorted data and output the data in the format supplied |

Note that if you are using this on files that are several gigabytes in size, you will need to have a machine that has a decent amount of memory or is sufficiently configured correctly to manage its memory correctly.

Comment: Thank you but whats if my value contain space ? for example one value is A C and this code as I understand separate by space thus this value will be 2 value 1 in A and 1 in C , is there any solution for this case?

Comment: Based on the type of data that is in the example, I'm going to assume that you are a student in some sort of medical or chemical science field. As such, allow me to share with you a *very important lesson*: state requirements up front. When people help a person only to hear "Oh, I have all these other things that need to be considered that I never told you", it becomes *very* easy for people to ignore all future requests. I work in education and have a lot of colleagues who have a lot of difficulty getting tech support because they never communicate everything up front.

Comment: Thank you very much on your helping and also for advising. Yesterday I wrote my real data here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74992499/count-specific-value-over-all-dataframe-in-python/74992682?noredirect=1# and wait run more than 10 hours so I convert to linux and I thank any data that I write is ok but when I try the suggested code not work for my data. Thus, can you help me with my real data please .. it's the same data but I convert dataframe to csv and without header and index.. THANKS VERY MUCH AGAIN.